# Exclude those observations from reference dataset which are found in exclusion set. Exclusion set evolves over time with new columns added

Tags: python, pyspark

**Problem**: Find a way to exclude only those observations/rows from the reference dataset which are present in the exclusion dataset. The number of columns and their respective exclusion conditions in the exclusion dataset could increase and change over time depending upon evolving needs. I want to develop a dynamic way to account for these additional conditional columns over time.

**Details**:

Reference dataset -

[image]

The exclusion dataset -

[image]

Originally, I had hard coded an anti-join as follows -

```
def list_sr(data: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
  """
  This function will expand (sequence and explode) the list of serial numbers.

  :param: data: Exclusion dataset
  :return: list of excluded sr numbers with effective dates.
  :rtype: Spark Dataframe.
  """

  sdf = (
        data
            .withColumn("sr_list", sequence(col('sr_start'), col('sr_end')))
            .withColumn('sr_number', explode(col('sr_list')))
    )

  return sdf


def implement_sr_exclusions(data: DataFrame,
                                sdf: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
    """
    This function will remove the list of serial numbers (exclusions) from the Reference dataset.

    :param: data: DataFrame. Reference dataset
    :param: df: DataFrame. List of excluded sr numbers.
    :return: Dataframe with excluded sr numbers removed.
    :rtype: Spark Dataframe.
    """


    data = (data.join(sdf,
                      (col('txn_date').between(col('date_start'), col('date_end')))
                      & (data.serial_number == sdf.sr_number),
                      'left_anti'))


    return data
```

which had the desired effect -

[image]

But now the needs have evolved and there is a need to add `customer_type` to the exclusion dataset and will likely look like this -

[image]

And it is likely that further columns could be added (such as `feature_1 > 1.03`) but no columns will be removed. It can also be assumed that the column names in the exclusion set may differ from those found in the reference set.

So I am looking for a way to dynamically create these conditonal rules on newly added columns.

It would be great if y'all could share some ideas on how I can go about achieving this.